# Ubuntu 18 on Dell PowerEdge R620, R720, or R820?

Tags: 18.04, dell

Has Anyone tried installing Ubuntu 18 on the Dell PowerEdge R620, R720, or R820 ?

There are a bunch of these refurbished units available, but Ubuntu only shows certification to Ubuntu 16 or 14.

However R610 is certified at Ubuntu 18.04...

Tks - Mark

Comment: I'm trying to install Ubuntu Server 20 on a Dell PowerEdge R710 with hw RAID10 (PERC 6/i) and no success so far. I've also tried lots of previous LTS versions (18, 16 and 14) and still no success. Setup goes smooth, but it falls to GRUB minimal-bash screen. For 18 and 20 live setups I get an error screen telling it couldn't scan my disks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Will my device work with Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/986878/will-my-device-work-with-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

Got Ubuntu 20.04 running nicely so far on an R620 or two here.  Seems OK, any troubles I'll post further but so far so good.