# How to install Ubuntu 20.04 or 22.04 - Dell PowerEdge R620?

Tags: server, uefi, dell, bios

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 22.04 on an R620, but no success so far...

BIOS Version is 2.9.0

Tried with Ubuntu 18.04 and Ubuntu 20.04, no success.

I already tried through a USB Bootable device and iDrac/virtual CD in BIOS and UEFI modes + AHCI and ATA modes. (Can't try with RAID because isn't an option.)

Also tried through Lifecycle Controller in both BIOS and UEFI modes, no success.

When I try in BIOS mode, an empty purple screen appears and it goes into a black screen after, and nothing happens.

When bios is in UEFI mode, grub install screen appears (install ubuntu screen), but when I select the option to install, also goes into a black screen and nothing happens.

I'm without options :/

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry, it wasn't clear in your post but have you tried a bootable USB stick with Ubuntu on it?  (Which you also test beforehand on another computer.)  Of course, also change the boot order so that USB is first.  Also, try 22.04 instead of 20.04.

Comment: @Ray I already tried with a bootable USB stick and with ubuntu 22.04 also :/

Comment: And you tested the USB stick on another computer to make sure it works?  I think that is the method you should focus on and don't bother with iDrac and/or the Lifecycle Controller.  Did it detect the USB stick?

Comment: @Ray Yes I tested the USB in a lot of other computers and they're ok :/... and Poweredge also detects USB stick. When BIOS is in UEFI mode, I can get into "install Ubuntu" black screen, but after I choose the option to install, it simply doesn't load it.  
And when I try to install with the BIOS in BIOS mode, a purple empty screen appears, and no matter what I press in keyboard, nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

This scenario could have if your ISO is corrupted or files are missing, it happens transferring the ISO or downloading it that some interruptions for X reason occurred. I would recommend *sha256 checksum* before creating a bootable usb stick, depending on your OS.

if you are on Ubuntu: https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-verify-ubuntu#1-overview

if you are on windows, using **rufus** to create a bootable ISO shall do it automatically for you and provide warnings if there's a mismatch.

**EDIT**

Try to boot into ubuntu using 'nomodest' option

- Boot into grub on UEFI mode and select try or install ubuntu
- Instead of 'Enter' click 'e' to edit the entry
- Find the line which start with `linux /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-xx-generic` and add `nomodest` at the end of the lign.
- Press `Crtl+x` or `F10` to boot with the modified parameter.

Hope this helps.

Comment: ISO isn't corrupted :/

Comment: What do you mean by "BIOS in UEFI mode" and "BIOS in BIOS mode" ? When you boot to grub menu you should see "try or install ubuntu" right ?

Comment: I mean that I can change bios mode in PowerEdge R620, and I tried to install in both modes, but didn’t work. 
Yes I see the “try or install” ubuntu option, but after I select it, throws me in a black empty screen and nothing happens. 
Tried with “nomodeset” option in grub, but also didnt work :/

Comment: I guess this machine doesn’t support Ubuntu at all :(

Comment: Did you checked the 256SHASUM as suggested ? you can try to boot using 'nomodest' option, i will provide a detailed answer on how to do so.

Comment: Please check this [ref](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1160791/ubuntu-18-on-dell-poweredge-r620-r720-or-r820) about R620 comptability

Comment: Hello! It did work and I installed Ubuntu 22.04, but when I rebooted, R620 just didn’t recognize OS :,(…

Comment: Tried to install 2 times, guess this model just doesn’t support and/or some driver is missing :/

Comment: If you find my instructions helpful, kindly upvote ^^

Comment: when dell logo appears try to hit F4 or F12 or F10 depending on the model, this would get you into grub menu and apply the previous steps to boot into ubuntu server entry

Comment: Also consider changing the boot sequence and make grub primary option